# Recaptcha 1.0 vs 2.0 in C#

Tags: c#, captcha, recaptcha

I am having difficulties verifying google's Recaptcha 2.0 response. (to be clear, using the exact script at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js).

I appear to have followed the instructions well enough to capture the response, but I then pass the response to my server to see if its valid, presumably by applying a calculation to the response using my secret key.

On the server side, I am using nuget's 'reCAPTCHA plugin for .NET' which has the most downloads of all the reCAPTCHA libraries I could find. The version is 1.0.5.0.

However, using the RecaptchaValidator, and supplying PrivateKey (Secret Key), RemoteIP and the Response, I can never get this thing to Validate() as being valid. I am not sure what the Challenge field is used for, I tried it as blank, or using my Site Key. Neither work.

However, I am now wondering if this library, while the most popular, is in fact not compatible to do a Validate command using ReCaptcha 2.0. Perhaps I came across a situation where 'the popular answer is the wrong answer'?

Anyone out there have success with ReCaptcha 2.0 and the Nuget package 1.0.5.0 before I start trying other libraries? I see a few alternatives, but they have very few downloads.

Comment: Try the code from my tutorial if you are still not succesfull: http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2015/04/no-captcha-recaptcha-for-aspnet-mvc.html This one is mvc, web forms is one below. It powers few working apps, works for sure then.

Comment: Very nice. I actually did something very similar in how I addressed it, using HttpRequest. It's too bad a little nuget package isn't out there yet for pure code-behind validation libraries (like the v1.0 lib) that do what this code does in a couple of lines. I imagine it'll be coming soon enough though..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but I'm pretty sure that it's not going to work.

reCAPTCHA 2.0 was released December 3rd, 2014 according to [this](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.hu/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html) blog post.

The [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/recaptcha/) was last published on February 14th, 2011.

So it can't really work as far as I can see.

Maybe you can try one from [this list](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/recaptcha) which says it can handle reCAPTCHA 2.0

[This](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RecaptchaNet) seems like the most recommended one and as you can see from the changelog it supports 2.0.

> v2.0
>
> 1. Support for reCAPTCHA v2 APIs.

Comment: I tried a few options, such as the one you suggested, but found they didn't quite work the way I wanted. In the end, I just coded the validation from scratch (took a couple of hours, but nothing crazy) using standard .NET libraries, and the information on [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). I will post that as the solution shortly, unless someone can post a specific example of a library, with a tested example, which I think would be the cleaner solution.